# Bash: tab completion selects by later part of file/directory name (like zsh)?

Tags: bash

Suppose I have these directories:

```
CSCI100
CSCI200
CSCI300
CSCI400
```

If I do

```
cd C<TAB>
```

it completes up to

```
cd CSCI
```

and then I must type a number to proceed.

Is there a way to do

```
cd 200<TAB>
```

which then alters the full command to

```
cd CSCI200
```

?

Comment: After reading some of the docs for Bash and Zsh I don't think this is within the usual scope of Bash.  Even in Zsh, wouldn't you have to do something like `cd 200<M-B><TAB>` to get completion at the beginning of the `200` part?  At that point, if you already knew that you were after the `200` directory, it would be just as fast to have typed `cd C<TAB>2<TAB>` or even `cd <TAB>2<TAB>`...

Comment: I thought that in zsh you could type partial filenames and tab to autocomplete/cycle through results?

Comment: It is possible, my only experience with it is reading a couple docs after reading your question.  :-)  In particular, one doc mentioned "completion occurs at the current cursor location..." which means (to me) that `cd 200<TAB>` would not do anything in Zsh.

Answer (score 4):

Bash's readline command "menu-complete" enables this behavior. You can either have this replace the Tab key's usual behavior (with the command `bind "Tab: menu-complete"`, or by putting "Tab: menu-complete" in your .inputrc file), or choose a different keyboard shortcut for this function.

EDIT: Sorry, I misunderstood the question; it's about completing a suffix rather than a prefix of a filename. You can sort of do this with the default settings in bash *if* you use a wildcard and there's only one match for the pattern:

```
cd *200<TAB>
```

expands to:

```
cd CSCI200
```

If there's more than one match, it'll list matches if you TAB again. Binding TAB to `menu-complete` will make it cycle through matches instead. I don't know of any way to do this in bash without explicitly giving a wildcard to tell it where to do the expansion.

Comment: I've done this and tested: It completes if I type cd C<TAB> and cycles through values, but doesn't work in the specific question asked above, which focuses on typing a *later* part of the directory and hitting tab, e.g., cd 300<TAB> => cd CSCI300 (it prepends CSCI to 300)